# Days between one date till today. Not difference (Spotfire)

Tags: datediff, spotfire

I'm trying to find how many days between a date and today.

I'm able to get the correct number of days but it show as negative.

```
Integer(DateDiff("day",Date(DateTimeNow()),Date([LAST_RECORD_DT])))
```

I would like the same result but positive number.

Comment: So I fixed this by using *-1
DateDiff("day",Date(DateTimeNow()),Date([LAST FILL RECORD DT])) * -1

I feel like there is a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer in your comment is good, but this is better in my opinion:

If `LAST_RECORD_DT` is in the past (which seems to be the case for you):

```
Integer(DateDiff("day",Date([LAST_RECORD_DT]),Date(DateTimeNow())))
```

If `LAST_RECORD_DT` is in the future:

```
Integer(DateDiff("day",Date(DateTimeNow()),Date([LAST_RECORD_DT])))
```

---

If you want it to always be positive, you can use `Abs`:

```
 Abs(Integer(DateDiff("day",Date([LAST_RECORD_DT]),Date(DateTimeNow()))))
```